# PHP Connection Receives Error on Load

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I'm receiving an *error message* when I load my page. This is the code:

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","","");
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die("died");
    }
        $db=mysql_select_db("kart",$conn);
        if(!$db)
        {
            echo(mysql_error($conn));
        }
        $query="select * from category";
        $result=mysql_query($query,$conn);
        if($result)
        {
            $row=mysql_num_rows($result);
            echo($row);
        }
        else
        {
            echo(mysql_error($conn));
        }
```

What's the cause for the *error message* and what should I do to resolve it?

**Error Message**:  *database not selected*

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: If this is a new application, you really shouldn't be using `mysql_query`. It's being removed from PHP.

Comment: before you even get started with mysql extension of php...give up now and use mysqli or pdo please

Comment: why is user="root" to be there as when i go to phpmyadmin, it doesn't asks to login

Comment: @tadman *"It's being removed from PHP."* - Actually that will depend if (all) hosting services update their servers accordingly to reflect upcoming changes to delete `MySQL_` altogether, correct?

Comment: i have added the error you can see

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, but `mysqli` is pretty much in every server so it wouldn't hurt to just convert the code now instead of later when most servers are updated and you are rushing to fix code.

Comment: @evan.stoddard Indeed, that's why I'm learning MySQLi and PDO right off the bat and not doing anything till I'm good and confidently ready.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry I read your response too fast.  I though you were saying that there's no need due to some servers not updating.  Glad to hear!

Comment: @evan.stoddard Not a problem Evan. It's best to do things right when working with DBs. I was on `dBASE IV` way back when and didn't keep going, but things weren't like today LOL! Cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- Exactly!  Totally agree!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Writing new code with `mysql_query` is just asking for trouble. Not only is it being removed, but it's very tricky to use correctly. A simple mistake can result in your entire server being trashed. Use PDO properly, like you suggest, and you won't have this exposure.

Comment: @tadman I agree. I'm not taking any chances on old technology, unless I know it's been proven to work efficiently without a hitch.

Comment: Where is the username for connecting to database in this $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","","");

Answer (score 0):

Check your username and password , if your are using WAMP or easy PHP , default user is `('root','')` and MAMP `('root,'root')`

**Syntax :**

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
```

**Try this :**

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

**or this :**

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the user, the default user is `root`

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                                 ^Here
```